# Anonymous functions and Maps in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm not sure why this doesn't work:

```
scala> case class Loader(n: String, x: String, l: List[String])
scala> val m: Map[String, (List[String])=>Loader] = 
     | Map("x" -> Loader("x", "x1", _:List[String]))              

<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (List[String]) => (java.lang.String, Loader)
 required: (String, (List[String]) => Loader)
       Map("x" -> Loader("x", "x1", _:List[String]))
```

but this does?

```
scala> Loader("t", "x", _:List[String])
res7: (List[String]) => Loader = function1>

scala> val m = Map("x" -> res7)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,(List[String]) => Loader] =
  Map((String,function1>))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parser was not sure where to put the beginning of the anonymous function. Sometimes you can solve this by adding another pair of parentheses (though not always):

```
val m: Map[String, (List[String])=>Loader] =
Map("x" -> (Loader("x", "x1", _:List[String])))
```

I don’t see any ambiguities here, so it might just not have been smart enough to figure it out. I think, the parser overlooked the possibility to have an anonymous function just after the `->` (which also is a library construct and uses *implicit* magic and all the wicket stuff which makes the little parser’s mind loop).

When you write it as an explicit tuple, it’ll work fine.

```
val m: Map[String, (List[String])=>Loader] =
Map(("x", Loader("x", "x1", _:List[String])))
```

Comment: Thx.  Yeah I noticed the same thing... that it worked with Tuples.

Answer (score 5):

One more victim of the overload of `_` in Scala. Consider this:

```
f(_, 5) + 1 // Partial function application
f(_ + 1, 5) // Closure
```

In the first case, `_` is replacing the entire parameter. In this case, it stands for a partial application of `f`. In practice, it's equivalent to `x => f(x, 5) + 1`, as the whole expression that *contains* `f` is turned into a closure.

In the second case, `_` is part of an expression. In this case, the whole expression is turned into a closure, up to any expression delimiter -- by which I mean that if the expression is nested inside another, only the inner expression is turned into a closure. In practice, it is equivalent to `f(x => x + 1, 5)`.