# How to restrict a anonymous function's boundary?

Tags: scala, function, casting, placeholder

I saw a below code:

```
Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two") map _._1
```

this return a Iterable[Int], but if I want to do nothing with map, how to do it?

I want to do something like below, but the below code can't compile, I know because it a object instance not a function, but how to create a function to do `x => x` and use placeholder:

```
Map(1 -> "one") map (_)  // map (Int, String) to (Int, String) by nothing change
// I test some other way, but all can't compile
```

how to do this?

UPDATED

Sorry for confuse passionate person. I want to know why `map (_) != map (x => x)`, compiler transform this code to `(x$1) => Map(1.$minus$greater("one")).map(x$1)` why not `Map('a'.$minus$greater(1)).map((x$1) => x$1)`, and does there has a way can use `_` make this code?

I used below code to help compiler inferred the `_` type:

```
Map(1 -> "one") map (_:((Int, String))=>(Int, String))
// but it return (((Int, String)) => (Int, String)) => scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = <function1>
```

It seem the parser was not sure where to put the beginning of the anonymous function. So my new question is "How to help the parser to restrict a anonymous function's boundary?"

Comment: Why do you need to do this using `map`? `Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two").toIterable` won't suffice?

Comment: sorry for confuse you, this just a question in my head, not a really question. No reason to do this, just want to know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but `identity` is maybe what you're looking for:

```
scala> Map(1 -> "one") map (identity)
res66: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map((1,one))
```

or, do some tricks:

```
scala> def __[A](x: A): A = x
__: [A](x: A)A

scala> Map(1 -> "one") map (__)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map((1,one))
```

Comment: :-) just think about such function

Comment: yes, this is what my wanted. Use scala inner method to do this. but does there has some other way that use placeholder to deal this? This question just from my crazy idea that want to know why `_ != x => x`, why _ can't be representative of a function like `Predef.identity` does. It's not a really question.

Answer (score 2):

I find a answer by Daniel, [Anonymous functions and Maps in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505125/anonymous-functions-and-maps-in-scala/3507163#3507163) , this answer let me clear how the parser process placeholder in this case. thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any value in what you're trying to do here, the correct way to map a collection to itself is not to call map!

Wrong:

```
Map(1 -> "one") map (_)
```

Right:

```
Map(1 -> "one")
```

It isn't even useful as a shallow copy operation, the default Scala Map is immutable and there's no point in copying it.

Comment: sorry for confuse you, like my above comment, this just a question in my head, not a really question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Map(1 -> "one") map((x)=>x)
```

Comment: sorry, I know that can do, but I want to use placeholder syntax to do this.